# How to append values from json file to tkinter combobox in python?

Tags: python, json, tkinter

I am trying to make profiles and save the json data to a txt file which i have done successfully, now i want to be able to search through my json file and add each of the profile names to the combobox. Here is an example of the json data generated.

```
{
"profile": [
    {
      "profile_name": 'name',
      "address": 'address',
      "city": 'yorktown',
    }
  ]
}
```

What ive tried to do with this is access the data with a for loop by saying

```
with open('profiles.txt', 'r') as file:
     profiles = json.load(file)
     for profile in profiles['profile']:
         profiles_select['values'] = profile['profile_name']
```

This solution works but only with one profile, as soon as i add a second profile i get this error

```
Extra data: line 19 column 1 (char 430)
```

The json file with more then one profile would look like this

```
{
"profile": [
    {
      "profile_name": 'name',
      "address": 'address',
      "city": 'yorktown',
    }
  ]
}
{
"profile": [
    {
      "profile_name": 'name',
      "address": 'address',
      "city": 'yorktown',
    }
  ]
}
```

so i thought that its because it doesnt know when to stop or start checking each value so i tried going by lines in the files. I tried this code

```
    with open('profiles.txt', 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for lines in file:
            profile_data = json.load(file)
            for profile in profile_data['profile']:
                profiles_select['values'] = profile['profile_name']
```

This yields no errors but returns no text in the profile combo box. If anyone has any insight here that would be very helpful.

Here is how i wrote my json data

```
    def save_profile():
        try:
            with open('profiles.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
                load_data_profile = json.load(infile)
        except:
            load_data_profile = {'profile': []}  # default when file can't be read
        load_data_profile['profile'].append({
            'profile_name': profile_name_entry.get(),
            'first_name': first_name_entry.get(),
            'last_name': last_name_entry.get(),
            'address': house_address_entry.get(),
            'address2': house_address2_entry.get(),
            'city': city_entry.get(),
            'country': country_entry.get(),
            'state': state_entry.get(),
            'zip': zip_entry.get(),
            'card_type': card_type_entry.get(),
            'card_number': card_number_entry.get(),
            'exp_month': card_exp_month_date_entry.get(),
            'exp_year': card_exp_year_date_entry.get(),
            'card_cvv': card_cvv_entry.get(),
            'phone': phone_entry.get(),
            'email': email_entry.get()
        })
        with open('profiles.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
            json.dump(load_data_profile, outfile, indent=4)
```

Comment: See LiveExample [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/LustrousWillingQuery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is wrong, so let's say it actually looks like this for more than one profile:

```
[{
"profile": [
    {
      "profile_name": 'name',
      "address": 'address',
      "city": 'yorktown',
    }
  ]
},
{
"profile": [
    {
      "profile_name": 'name',
      "address": 'address',
      "city": 'yorktown',
    }
  ]
}]
```

Now in that case you should be able to parse it like so:

```
with open('profiles.txt', 'r') as file:
     profiles = json.load(file)
     for item in profiles:
         profile = item["profile"]
         profiles_select['values'] = profile['profile_name']
```

But note that really you don't need the `profile` key here at all. You could just have a JSON array of objects:

```
    [{
      "profile_name": 'name',
      "address": 'address',
      "city": 'yorktown',
    },
    {
      "profile_name": 'name',
      "address": 'address',
      "city": 'yorktown',
    }]
```

And then have:

```
with open('profiles.txt', 'r') as file:
     profiles = json.load(file)
     for profile in profiles:
         profiles_select['values'] = profile['profile_name']
```

Comment: would you mind helping me edit my json? i just edited it to show the json code.

Comment: I've given two possible alternative formats in the answer. What help do you need?

Comment: (Hint: you're missing commas between the items in the array, and missing square brackets around the whole thing to show it's an array.)

Comment: only one issue is that when i use ```profiles_select['values'] = profile['profile_name']``` it only shows the most recent name bc this is over writting the previous value. Now when doing it like this, ```profiles_select['values'] = (profiles_select['values'], add_profile)``` it only shows the first 2 until it adds the values onto each string in the box, so say i made 3 profiles called ```test, main, main2``` it prints ```test main2, 
main``` where test and main2 are on the same line and main is the second value. To be more clear if i made a 4th profile it would then add that one next to main.

Comment: @seesharper It's not yours, the OP should have to clarify. In the meantime it's solved in a folloup question: [`Why is my python function printing out {}Main and not just Main?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59805299)