# Why is my python function printing out {}Main and not just Main?

Tags: python, json, tkinter

I am using a function to grab my data from a json file and print it to a tkinter combo box, for some reason the first word always has {} in front of it. My json data doesn't have it so why does it appear in my output?

```
    with open('profiles.txt', 'r') as file:
        profiles = json.load(file)
        for profile in profiles:
            add_profile = profile['profile_name']
            profiles_select['values'] = (profiles_select['values'], add_profile)
```

Values is also preset to have nothing in it so the values container code looks like this: `profiles_select = ttk.Combobox(new_task_frame1, width=10, values=[])`

Here is the json sample data:

```
[
    {
        "profile_name": "Main",
        "first_name": "Michael ",
    },
    {
        "profile_name": "Test",
        "first_name": "Michael ",
    }
]
```

This is what i expect to show up in my tkinter combo box :

```
Main
Test
```

This is what actually outputs

```
{}Main
Test
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You haven't showed any code that creates or enters data into a combobox.

Comment: @BryanOakley i showed both of those... The ```profiles_select['values'] = (profiles_select['values'], add_profile)``` in the first block of code shows me adding the values into the combo box. I also showed the creation of the box which was ```profiles_select = ttk.Combobox(new_task_frame1, width=10, values=[])```

Comment: Should be `profile_select['values'].append(add_profile)`.

Comment: @acw1668 you cannot directly append that, it returns ```'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Then change the whole for loop to `profiles_select['values'] = tuple(x['profile_name'] for x in profiles)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: Why is my python function printing out `'{}Main'` and not just '`Main'`?

- Initalizing `profiles_select['values']`

  ```
  profiles_select = ttk.Combobox(new_task_frame1, width=10, values=[])
  ```

  This results, widget internal, to: `''`, `tcl` uses: `'{}'`

---

- Adding options

  ```
  profiles_select['values'] = (profiles_select['values'], add_profile)
  ```

  You take the internal value `''`and a new option `'Main'`, which results in `('', 'Main')`.

---

- How `tkinter` shows the `Listbox` options

  > Your **two** options:

  ```
  {}Main  
  Test
  ```

  > More than **two** options:

  ```
  profiles_select['values'] = ('{{{} Main} Test} Test2', 'Test3')

  {{{} Main} Test} Test2
  Test3
  ```

---

> **Conclusion, don't update options using**:
>   `profiles_select['values'] = (profiles_select['values'], add_profile)`

---

> **Solution**: Create your sequence first and assign it in whole once.

```
with open('profiles.txt', 'r') as file:
    profiles = json.load(file)

    options = []
    for profile in profiles:
        options.append(profile['profile_name'])

    profiles_select['values'] = options
```